# Windows 10 not detecting once disabled/removed display

Tags: windows

I have 2 external displays connected to my windows 10 laptop and all 3 were working fine before I accidentally dropped one of the external display while rearranging them through display setting. Selected display was dragged out side of displays pan and dropped. Now the monitor appears to be lost for ever and windows not detecting it any more. Struggling hard to get it back.
Restarted windows, unplugged hdmi cable and plugged it back. Updated video drivers
Removed reg keys

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Connectivity

displays appeared to reset but lost display still not being detected.

How can I request windows to forgive my mistake and return my lost display back?

**EDIT**
Also tried to delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY by following [this](http://myitforum.com/myitforumwp/2012/09/24/cleaning-up-old-pc-monitor-data/) but could not take ownership or access on some of the subkeys so failed.

Comment: "but could not take ownership or access on some of the subkeys so failed." - Sounds like you are not an Administrator on the machine.

Comment: @Ramhound I am the only user and administrator as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved my issue, this may be helpful to others:

1. Download PSEXEC and unzip to some folder.
2. Open an elevated CMD prompt as an administrator.
3. Navigate to the folder where you unzipped PSEXEC.EXE
4. Run:
    PSEXEC -i -s -d CMD
5. You will have a new CMD prompt open, as though by magic.
6. Type the following in the new CMD prompt to prove who you are:
    WHOAMI /USER
7. Run regedit and delete registry key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY

It will not complain about access issues:
More details are [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/10/22/getting-a-cmd-prompt-as-system-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008/).